# How to load custom JS and dependencies using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, theme, requirejs

I'm struggling to understand where and how to correctly configure RequireJS to load my custom JS and it's dependencies. What I have below is working but I don't think it's set up correctly.

My theme requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'myapp': '"js/myapp"',
        'owlcarousel': 'js/vendor/owl.carousel',
    },
    shim: {
        'myapp': {
            deps: ['jquery','owlcarousel']
        },
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
};
```

My custom JS myapp.js

```
require(['jquery','owlcarousel'], function($){

    var myCarousel = $(".carousel").owlCarousel();
    console.dir($); 
    console.log(myCarousel);

});
```

To get myapp.js to output as expected, I have to put the following in one of my template files but if I load it just after the body tag it gives an error, which suggest that my script it not waiting for require resources before it runs and only works by chance if it's loads later.

```
<script>
    require (['js/sozoapp'], function() {});
</script>
```

Can anyone explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you plz change with above code,

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'myapp': 'js/myapp',
        'owlcarousel': 'js/vendor/owl.carousel',
    },
    shim: {

        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },

        'myapp': {
            deps: ['jquery','owlcarousel']
        },
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh. After making your changes and moving the following code after the body tag it now works.

`<script>
 require (['js/myapp'], function() {});
</script>`

But am right to include the code above after the body tag and should myapp.js also include?

`require(['jquery','owlcarousel']`

Comment: you can add anyplace your require js code in template

Comment: its working at any place?

Comment: Yes it works now when I add `<script> require (['js/myapp'], function() {}); </script>` straight after the body tag. But do I need the following in myapp.js  `require(['jquery','owlcarousel'] ` ?

Comment: I believe you do @PaulBenbow - Without it the script wouldn't have access to Owl Carousel. You could always remove it and see if it breaks, I suspect it will.

Comment: @Ben-Space48 yes you're right, it does error without it in the 'owlcarousel' in myapp.js.